How can i get my wordpress blog to filter by and select both cats and tags at the same time, right now this only lets me select them separate
How can I get my WordPress blog to filter by and select both cats and tags at the same time, right now this only lets me select them separately but it does work, I need to be able to filter them both individually at the same time with different tags and different cats
// FILTER CATEGORIES
$('#support > div').not(':first').hide();
    $('#filter .menu li:first-child').addClass('active');
    
    $('#filter .menu a').on('click', function() {
        $('#filter .menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var acts_link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#support > div').hide();
        $(acts_link).show();
        return false;
    });
// END FILTER CATEGORIES

